# vulkan command buffers synchronization for the case of updating the command buffer

Tags: vulkan

Suppose we have 3 command buffers A, B and C. All enable `VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_SIMULTANEOUS_USE_BIT` when they are created. The dependencies are as follows:

- B -> A
- C -> B, the next image in the swapchain

The synchronization between them is done using semaphores. In the most of time, I can pre-create A, B and C and then just submit them one after another to the rendering queue in the rendering loop. At some time point, I want to **modify** the command buffer A. However, the problem is that several A have been submitted into the rendering queue. I think at that time point the rendering queue may look like

A B C A B

I cannot modify command buffer A because it is being executed or queued by the GPU. The most naive way is to call `vkQueueWaitIdle` on the CPU side to wait for all CBs to be done. Then I can modify A and continue back to my rendering sequence. The problem for this method is that it will wait all CBs to be done. In my opinion, I only need to wait for all As to be done in the queue as opposed to waiting for all CBs. Is it possible to do it? Is there a better way to modify A without calling `vkQueueWaitIdle`?

Comment: "*The synchronization between them is done using semaphores.*" Why? If they're all executing on the same queue, semaphores aren't especially useful. You may as well be using events/barriers.

Comment: @NicolBolas sometimes, I want to do A,C without B or B,C without A. By separeting them into different command buffers and represent the dependencies using semaphores, I don't need to rebuild the command buffers. For example, say my rendering sequence is ABC and C's shader reads the textures generated from B and A. Under my idea, when my rendering sequence changes to BC, I can use a uniform variable to tell C that I don't have A anymore so C's shader will not read A's texture and my rendering sequence becomes BC. If I use barrier or event, I think I need to rebuild C's command buffer.

Comment: That doesn't explain why you're using a semaphore to express dependencies for things within the same queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't modify the command buffer. Create a new one and record into that. It really shouldn't matter whether it's the command buffer object `A` or some alternative command buffer object `A'`. What matters are the commands you record into it.

In any case, the typical way to know when an operation is finished with a command buffer (or some set thereof) is to use a fence at queue submission time. Fences are particularly coarse grained, but you can query information about their status from the CPU.

Comment: Is this what you mean: I create a fence each time I submit A to the queue. When I want to update/modify A, I create a new command buffer and submit it to the queue. At the same time, I check whether the previous As are done by checking the fences. If they are done, I destroy them.

Comment: @user3677630: Submitting stuff to a queue is an *incredibly* heavyweight operation. It's so heavy that the Vulkan specification itself contains a note explicitly telling you to minimize the number of times you submit stuff to a queue. Ideally, you should submit stuff to the queue exactly once per frame. So the fence isn't about telling when a particular CB is done; it's about detecting when a rendering operation which may contain that particular CB is finished.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I did not know that "*Submitting stuff to a queue is an incredibly heavyweight operation*". I think it must be why you ask me the reason I'm using semaphores. If submitting is heavy, then it is better to put everything into one command buffer. In fact, I did a comparison between using one command buffer with barriers and several render passes and multiple (5 in my case) command buffers with semaphores. The first option gives ~5% more FPS.

Comment: @user3677630: "*If submitting is heavy, then it is better to put everything into one command buffer.*" ... what? It's not about the number of command buffers; one call to `vkQueueSubmit` can accept many command buffers. It's about using *just one call*. And not having needless synchronization between them.